# Meaning of TLT TRT RTT LTL

Tags: luatex

Would please someone explain the meaning, perhaps by means of a hand-drawn sketch, of these four values in connexion with the LuaTeX commands `\pagedir`, `\bodydir`, `\pardir`, `\textdir`, `\mathdir` and `\boxdir`?

Comment: Good discussion from someone called D. Carlisle here:  https://www.tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2016-November/006279.html

Comment: See also section 2.3 of this:  http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatex.pdf

Comment: @Thruston ... and also section 7.1.2.15 "dir nodes".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in comments under the question, I posted something to the luatex list last year with some notes on these. To save people unpacking an attachment from the mail archives, I'll add it here as plain TeX. There have been several updates to the manual since I drafted this so it may need extending/correcting in places.

```
% Some attempt at describing luatex's direction commands
% David Carlisle
% You may copy, modify and use without restriction.

\catcode`\|\active
\def|#1|{{\tt\detokenize\expandafter{\string#1}}}
\suppressoutererror1

\beginsection Direction identifiers.

The luatex system distinguishes four different directions,
TLT, TRT, RTT, LTL.
The three letters in the name denote three aspects of the typesetting direction behavior.

\item 1
The direction towards the ``top'' of the paragraph
(that is, the start of the vertical mode direction)
is one of
T(top), L(left), R(right).

For English and Arabic, the beginning of the paragraph is T;

for Japanese it is R;

for Mongolian it is L.


\item 2
The direction towards the beginning of the line
(that is, the start of the horizontal mode direction)
is one of
T(top), L(left), R(right).

Defines  where  each  line  begins.

For  English, it is L;

for Arabic, it is R;

for Japanese and Mongolian, it is T.


\item 3
The top of the glyphs within the line
is one of
T(top), L(left).

\bigskip

These result in the following typical settings:

TLT for English,

TRT for  Arabic,

RTT for  Japanese,

LTL for  Mongolian.


\beginsection Direction registers.

The direction state is stored in five registers as listed below

\halign{&# \hfil\cr
page &|tex.pagedir|& |\pagedir|\cr
text &|tex.textdir|& |\textdir|, |\linedir|\cr
mathematics &|tex.mathdir|& |\mathdir|\cr
body &|tex.bodydir|& |\bodydir|\cr
paragraph &|tex.pardir|& |\pardir|\cr}



Each of these primitives takes as primitive one of the above four writing directions.


\item{|\pagedir|}



{\it
Can |\bodydir| be different to |\pagedir|? If it is different get warning
warning  (backend):
  pagedir differs from bodydir, the output may be placed wrongly on the page
\par}


\item{|\pardir|}

This defines the direction of the paragraph building.\par
In the default |\pagedir| TLT |\bodydir| TLT |\textdir| TLT then

TLT:
paragraph indentation left of first line, at top.
|\rightskip| fills from the right and |\parfillskip| fills the bottom line, from the right

TRT:
paragraph indentation left of first line, at top.
|\rightskip| fills from the left and |\parfillskip| fills the bottom line from the left,

LTL
paragraph indentation left of first line, at top.
|\rightskip| is a vertical skip after each line

RTT
paragraph indentation vertical above first line, at top.
|\rightskip| is a vertical skip after each line


\item{|\textdir|}
This primitive can appear anywhere in a text.
Grouping is respected, so it is possible to have inserts within a
paragraph.

The |\linedir| primitive sets the same text direction parameter but
with a modified positioning of the direction nodes with respect to white
space, which is convenient in some cases. Compare the two examples below.


|abc {\textdir TRT xyz \textdir TLT 123} abc|

abc {\textdir TRT xyz \textdir TLT 123} abc

|abc {\linedir TRT xyz \linedir TLT 123} abc|

abc {\linedir TRT xyz \linedir TLT 123} abc


Note how in the first case the space after |xyz| in the source
is affected by the direction and so ends up visually adjacent to the
space after |abc|, with no space visible between xyz and 123.
|\linedir| adjusts the position of inserted direction nodes relative
to adjacent space characters so that text runs remain separated by the
spaces.


\item{|\mathdir|}
Normally mathematics is done in the same direction as English, namely
TLT There have been situations where it has been written TRT.

TLT: left to right\par
TRT: Right to left\par
LTL: down with superscripts to the left\par
RTT: down with superscripts to the right\par


\beginsection Box directions

\item {|\boxdir|}

The |\boxdir| primitive allows the direction of a previously
constructed box register to be altered.

For example:

|\newbox\bxA|\par
|\setbox\bxA\hbox{abc}|\par
|1 \box\bxA\ 2 \boxdir\bxA TRT\ box\bxA|

Produces
%  1 abc 2 cba

\newbox\bxA
\setbox\bxA\hbox{abc}
1 \copy\bxA\ 2 \boxdir\bxA TRT\ \copy\bxA

Note that this only specifies the initial direction, any direction
nodes that were saved in the box are retained with their original values.

|\newbox\bxB|\par
|\setbox\bxB\hbox{\textdir TLT abc}|\par
|1 \copy\bxB\ 2 \boxdir\bxB TRT\ \copy\bxB|

Produces
% 1 abc 2 abc

\newbox\bxB
\setbox\bxB\hbox{\textdir TLT abc}
1 \copy\bxB\ 2 \boxdir\bxB TRT\ \copy\bxB


\beginsection Direction nodes

to be added\dots

\beginsection balancing the direction stack.

Something about how dirction nodes are constructed to add |+| or |-|
prefixed direction nodes to generate a balanced stack for the back end
processing\dots


\beginsection |local_par| nodes

Perhaps, add something, as far as they relate to directionality\dots

\beginsection Paragraph Shape.

Something about |\parshape| and |\shapemode| to be added\dots


\bye
```

Comment: Thanks. I get an error: `This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)...! Undefined control sequence. l.126 abc {\linedir ...`

Comment: `s/\\linedir/\\textdir/g`?

Comment: Can we expect this to be incorporated into the e-TeX based engines (`pdftex`, `xetex`) one day too?

Comment: @AlexG pdftex no chance, xetex I'd hoped so but I suspect not. (more likely that we work out a usable way of calling harfbuzz from luatex, as a means of combining xetex and luatex capabilities)

Comment: @AlexG Your luatex is too old, `\linedir` was added in 1.0.

Comment: The outcome of  `abc { \textdir TRT xyz \textdir TLT 123} abc` puzzles me, really. Isn't the effect of `\textdir` supposed to be local to the current group? How can the second `abc` be typeset in reverse order, and how can it appear next to the first `abc`?

Comment: @AlexG that makes (in visual order) `abc\ \ zyx123\ abc` isn't that what you expect? (using 1.0.2, maybe something got fixed if you are using an older luatex and it does something diferent)

Comment: Yes, this is what I expected, while v0.95 gives "abc cba 123 zyx".

Comment: Hopefully, v1.0 makes it into TeXLive-2017.

Comment: @AlexG oh it will yes, it's been in the texlive svn trunk for some months already.

Comment: What do you mean by "the top of the a glyph within a line" ? What mogolian have an L at third digit?

Comment: I once made a picture for the (typically used) TLT, TRT, RRT and LTL settings: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410087/47927

Comment: As to the question “Can \bodydir be different to \pagedir?”, the answer is yes. In fact, in `babel` they are often different, except in the output routine.