# How to use \boxdir primitive

Tags: luatex, right-to-left

From luatex manual version 1.15 (page 43):

> The direction related primitives \pagedir, \bodydir, \pardir,
> \textdir, \mathdir and \boxdir are now core primitives.

I wanted to know how to use the command. so with `\boxdir TRT` we have error `Missing number, treated as zero`,  and with `\boxdir 0`  we have error `Bad direction <to be read again> \scan_stop`.

If anyone has knowledge of how to use the command, please explain about it, thank you.

Comment: \boxdir expects first a box number, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351558/2388

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer That's what I was looking for.